# How to calculate percentage in BIP rtf template?

Tags: rtf, obiee, bi-publisher

| Status | % | Total No. of Population | % | Male Population | % | Female Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 50 | 30 | 66.66 | 20 | 33.33 | 10 |
| XXXX | 50 | 30 | 33.33 | 10 | 66.66 | 20 |
| Total | 100 | 60 | 100 | 30 | 100 | 30 |

The query for the dataset is huge and includes group by.
So, how can I calculate percentage in the report itself?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to create different data set for grand total and then calculate the percentage but its not working.

Comment: Can you update what the data set looks like in the database, what the XML output looks like, what the RTF looks like (code showing XML elements would be nice), what the processed output looks like, and then what you expect?  Also, what system are you using to do this? (E-Business Suite, etc..). Your question is quite ambiguous and full of unknowns.